# Share via AirDrop only

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I want to bring out the share sheet with the AirDrop as the only option in my application.

In iOS 7, I could simple add all share types to the `excludedActivityTypes` property of `UIActivityViewController` (`UIActivityTypeMessage`, `UIActivityTypeMail`, ...)

But now in iOS 8, with the app extensions, the users may have extra sharing providers that show up. 
Is there any way to show AirDrop *only*?

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[[NSURL URLWithString:url]]
                                                                         applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail,
                                UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
class AirDropOnlyActivityItemSource : NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

    /// The item you want to send via AirDrop.
    let item: AnyObject

    init(item: AnyObject) {
        self.item = item
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        /// Use an empty URL as placeholder to let iOS Share Sheet show the AirDrop only.
        return NSURL(string: "")!
    }

    func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return item
    }   
}
```

Comment: Works Very Well!

Comment: How to do in React Native, please?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2 version of [Jonny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36573915/3151675):

```
class AirDropOnlyActivityItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    ///The item you want to send via AirDrop.
    let item: Any

    init(item: Any) {
        self.item = item
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        //using NSURL here, since URL with an empty string would crash
        return NSURL(string: "")!
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return item
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let itemSource = AirDropOnlyActivityItemSource(item: "test")

let activityVc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [itemSource], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: How to add another built-in iOS App? (eg: `Message`, `Photos`...)

Comment: UIActivityViewController is a great convenience, but I would like to send the files programmatically rather than manually. I want myDeviceApp to scan for all devices that have AirDrop enabled, get UUID of each device and send concurrently or synchronously a picture or video to all devices. 
Is this possible?

Comment: I'm currently getting the error "Method does not override any method from its superclass" on the two internal funcs. :(

Answer (score -1):

That's currently not possible. You should file an [enhancement request with apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) explaining why this would be useful to the user/developer.