# How to keep only the airdrop option in the UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

In my application I want to bring out the share sheet with the Airdrop as the only option.

I saw the answer to a question similar to it.:
[Share via Airdrop only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607781/share-via-airdrop-only)
But it doesn't work.

```
func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
    /// Use an empty URL as placeholder to let iOS Share Sheet show the AirDrop only.
    return NSURL(string: "")!
}

func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
    return item
}
```

I want to bring out the share sheet with the Airdrop as the only option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDAcT.png)

Comment: You can exclude activity types with `excludedActivityTypes` in `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Here is a working version for Swift 4.2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185547/3151675

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share via Airdrop only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607781/share-via-airdrop-only)

Comment: I want to delete the [...] icon, My needs are different from this one  Share via Airdrop only.