# how to share only built-in iOS app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share video file via only built-in iOS apps.
 And I want third-party apps hide from `UIActivityViewController`'s list.

I Found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185547/10283519
This answer makes it possible share only `AirDrop`.

How to add built-in iOS apps? (eg: `Photos`, `Files`, `Mail`...)

Answer (score 0):

You can not add option menually, it will display automatically according to share content, for example, if share content is only text then not show "iCloud photo sharing" But share content has the image then automatically show option accordingly.

If you want to hide/remove options from `UIActivityViewController` then you can do this using `excludedActivityTypes` property of  `UIActivityViewController`, See following code for this.

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [.print, .mail, .airDrop, .assignToContact, .copyToPasteboard, .addToReadingList, .markupAsPDF, .message, .openInIBooks, .postToTwitter, .postToFacebook]
        present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I know `excludedActivityTypes`. But I want hide third-party app.

Comment: Hi Downvoter what's the wrong with this code, Please add comment to update the answer.